# how to link to Lua api from Xcode c++ project

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, api, lua

I downloaded the Lua source code for version 5.2.2 and built Lua on my macOS version 10.8. (Mountain Lion).

I used the following to build:

```
make macosx install
```

These are the things that were installed on /usr/local/:

```
bin: lua luac
include: lua.h luaconf.h lualib.h lauxlib.h lua.hpp
lib: liblua.a
man/man1: lua.1 luac.1
```

I started Xcode (4.6) and created a new C++ console project. I then included the following header files:

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"
```

I then wrote a little program to create a new lua state and then load all lua libraries and at the end close the lua state as follows:

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
lua_close(L);
```

My build fails with the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"luaL_newstate()", referenced from:
    _main in main.o
"luaL_openlibs(lua_State*)", referenced from:
    _main in main.o
"lua_close(lua_State*)", referenced from:
    _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I would be really grateful if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: have you checked those symbols? Perhaps you have the 32 bit lua lib, not 64?

Comment: You need to link against the lua library.

Comment: @Yu Hao: have you made sure you are linking against the 64 bit library when trying to do a 64 bit build?